# Guarding an Angular 2/4/5 lazy loaded route from being served in Express.js

Tags: node.js, angular, express, lazy-loading

I'm (very) new to Express.js, but I'm looking for a way to guard from serving a particular Angular 2+ lazy-loaded route unless the user has logged in with certain privileges? I'm not worried about the authentication part, just need to know how prevent a file (Angular module) from being served under certain conditions. Is this standard or non-standard?

[Edit]: I'm not looking for a font-end solution to prevent the *request*. I'm looking for a backend solution to prevent the resource from being *served*.

Comment: This is standard, you're looking for Angular - `CanLoad`

Comment: I've updated my question. I'm not looking for a front-end solution to this problem.

Comment: Good info here. Possibly a duplicate: stackoverflow.com/questions/43805982